# How can I emit the result of storm botl to kafka brokers using kafkabolt?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm trying to change the wordcount example in storm: instead of displaying the result, I want to send it to kafka cluster. 
This is code which build the topology:

```
 Config config = new Config();
    config.setDebug(true);
    config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);
//set producer properties.
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("acks", "1");
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
config.put("kafka.broker.config", props);
KafkaBolt bolt = new KafkaBolt()
            .withTopicSelector(new DefaultTopicSelector("tt"))
            .withTupleToKafkaMapper(new FieldNameBasedTupleToKafkaMapper())
                        .withProducerProperties(props);

    BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
    SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, "test", "", "id1");
    spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new KafkaBoltKeyValueScheme());
    KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);     
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("line-reader-spout", kafkaSpout);
    builder.setBolt("word-spitter", new WordSpitterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("line-reader-spout");
    builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("word-spitter");
    builder.setBolt("forwardToKafka", bolt,1).shuffleGrouping("word-counter");
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("HelloStorm", config, builder.createTopology());
```

As you can see, I want to send the result of wordcounter bolt to kafka topic. However, I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: message does not exist
at org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields.fieldIndex(Fields.java:95) ~[storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.tuple.TupleImpl.fieldIndex(TupleImpl.java:100) ~[storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.tuple.TupleImpl.getValueByField(TupleImpl.java:149) ~[storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.kafka.bolt.mapper.FieldNameBasedTupleToKafkaMapper.getMessageFromTuple(FieldNameBasedTupleToKafkaMapper.java:46) ~[storm-kafka-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.kafka.bolt.KafkaBolt.process(KafkaBolt.java:120) [storm-kafka-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseTickTupleAwareRichBolt.execute(BaseTickTupleAwareRichBolt.java:38) [storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4963$tuple_action_fn__4965.invoke(executor.clj:731) [storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__4884.invoke(executor.clj:461) [storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__4398.onEvent(disruptor.clj:40) [storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:453) [storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:432) [storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:73) [storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4963$fn__4976$fn__5029.invoke(executor.clj:850) [storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:484) [storm-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
```

7793 [Thread-18-forwardToKafka-executor[2 2]] INFO  o.a.s.d.executor - BOLT fail TASK: 2 TIME: -1 TUPLE: source: word-counter:4, stream: default, id: {}, ["publish"}]

In word count bolt, I have done this:

```
String str = input.getString(0);
collector.emit(new Values(str));
    collector.ack(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add `declarer.declare(new Fields("message"))` in your bolt's `public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer)` function
like is :

```
public class MessageBolt extends BaseBasicBolt {

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
        String word = (String) input.getValue(0);
        String out = word ;
        collector.emit(new Values(out));
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("message"));
    }
}
```